# Separating comma broken words in PHP and selecting extra information

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to look into this for a while now but can't find an answer that explains the coding properly.  Basically I have a mysql table with 'connections' relevant to a user.  These connections are separated with a comma:

connection1, connection2, connection3, connection4, etc

What I need to do is to separate each one into an array like so:

```
$connection1
$connection2
$connection3
$connection4
```

Then for each of these I need to be able to select sertain information from a different table, so for example:

```
(SELECT name,id FROM users WHERE username = (all of the connections above))
```

Could any of you let me kow how this would be possible? Thank you

Comment: This is all pretty basic stuff - have you tried to do anything yourself?

Comment: separating string to array is done with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in php.

Comment: It's basically the selecting of information where all connections part which I'm stuck on

Comment: `$connection1, $connection2, $connection3, $connection4` is not an array; is problem about PHP (as the title suggests) or about MySQL? Also, if you are storing comma separated values in a database and are planning to search for them, you should consider to normalize the database structure first.

Comment: It is possible in SQL (see my answer below) but it is messy, inefficient and likely to be difficult for people to understand in future. While splitting the string in php and then doing a separate select for each user (or worse, for each connection for each user) is likely to be even less efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple. Use `explode` function of php.

```
   $text= "connection1, connection2, connection3, connection4";
   $res= explode(",",$text);

    foreach($res as $i=>$id)
    {
       echo $res[$i];
    }
```

Comment: I should probably have specified that I'm not going to be sure how many connections are going to be in the cell as connections will be added and deleted regularly. Is there a way of making it so that the $res[0] is counted automatically or would I have to count the $res and do something from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FIND_IN_SET to do a JOIN, or you can join against a table of integers and use that with Substring_index to get the values from the CSV string

Normally a comma separated list in a database is the sign of poor design. Better to split them off into another table, with one row for each item in the comma separated list.

EDIT - Example of how to do it using a table of integers:-

```
SELECT name,id 
FROM users a
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat(Connection, ','), ',', aCnt), ',', -1) AS aConnection
FROM Connections
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100 + 1 AS aCnt
FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) Sub1
WHERE (LENGTH(Connection) + 1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(Connection, ',', ''))) >= aCnt) Sub2
ON a.username = Sub2.aConnection
```

This relies on a table called integers with a single column called i, with 10 rows with the values 0 to 9. You can cross join this against itself to get a range of numbers. In this case from 0 to 999, then limited by the number of commas in the field you are splitting up. This value is then used to find the commas for SUBSTRING_INDEX to split the string up.